# Screen sharing Ops Main Screen

Tags: screen-sharing

I am looking for a way to share the output of a operations screen to multiple remote developers and admins and displaying on a large LCD TV.

Ideally It would be something that can run undisturbed in its own window on their machines either as a web or windows application. If they can also use it to control the main screen when needed that would be great.

Comment: Is there a reason VNC wouldn't work for you? It's pretty ghetto, but sometimes it's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

We just use a separate computer, keyboard, and mouse in our datacenter. The computer has long VGA cables that go from the computer to the projectors in the NOC. The viewing area on the wall is about 30 ft x 10 ft.

What's on the screen is an html page with embedded web content from various monitoring portals (temperature, system performance, weather, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about displaying on LCD TV, but www.yuuguu.com allows up to 30 people to view and control a remote desktop using just a browser. Piece of cross platform client software sits on machine with operations screen, then developers admins would connect in using a Flash 9 equipped web browser. Most browsers have that capabiility.

Our secrity model might be backwards for your needs though - a human has to start the screen share going at the ops machine in the first place.